# How to center a group of SVG shapes with Snap.SVG & Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, snap.svg

I'm trying to make a circle of rectangles, to be centered (vertically and horizontally) in an SVG

here's my code so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/JamThom/7G2pC/

```
    var a = Snap(250,250);

for (var i=0;i<90;i++) {
var sqz = a.rect(0, 0, 14, 3)
.attr({
    fill: '#666',
    transform: "r"+i*4+",75,0"
})
.data("i",i);
}
```

In order to do this I believe I need to first select and group all of the rectangles, but as I created them in a for loop they don't have individual names and I don't know how to target them

any help appreciated
and apologies for the ameteur-ness of my code - this is my first experience with snap.svg

Answer (score 1):

You can move it to the center using `translate`:

```
 transform: "t50,125 r"+i*4+",75,0"
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/DsQ5w/)

Your SVG is 250x250 and the radius is 75, so the coordinates for `t` are `250 / 2 - 75 = 50` and `250 / 2 = 125`. In the fiddle I used variables.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a slight variation to helderdarocha for an answer, you can as you mention add them to a group and translate, like this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DsQ5w/2/)

```
var skillometer = Snap(size, size);
var g = skillometer.g();
g.attr({ transform: 't' + x + ',' + y });

for (var i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
    var sqz = skillometer.rect(0, 0, 14, 3)
        .attr({
        fill: '#666',
        transform: "r" + i * 4 + "," + radius + ",0"
    }).data("i", i);
    g.append( sqz );    

}

// you can now animate or move the whole group as one.
g.animate({ transform: 't'+x+','+y+'s1.65' }, 5000 );
```

There's not a lot of difference, unless you want to move or animate the whole lot, in which case this group method may be preferable, as you can move the group in the future with a transform on just the group element (have included that just to highlight).